# UI5 routing doesn't instantiate a view

Tags: javascript, view, routes, sapui5

I've some routes in my Component. I want to navigate to the URL "URL/#/Reports". Here are my routes:

```
routes: [
                {
                    pattern: "",
                    name: "menu",
                    view: "Menu",
                    targetAggregation: "pages",
                    targetControl: "idAppControl"
                },
                {
                    pattern: "Reports",
                    name: "reports",
                    view: "SplitContainer",
                    targetAggregation: "pages",
                    targetControl: "idAppControl",
                    clearTarget: true,
                    subroutes: [
                        {
                            pattern: "Reports/SFC",
                            name: "sfcsub",
                            view: "SFCReport",
                            targetControl: "idSplitContainerControl",
                            targetAggregation: "masterPages"
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
```

It's kind of working, though. This means that if I'm clicking on a menu item to the /Reports path the "Menu" view disappears. The problem is that the "SplitContainer" view isn't loaded/instantiated. There are no DOM elements. 
The crazy thing is, if I'm reloading the page (with the URL "URL/#/Reports") I'm getting the SplitContainer view just fine.

Function leading to the Report path:

```
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this).navTo("reports", {
    from: "menu"
}, bReplace);
```

Comment: Does it load the SplitContainer view files? Did you try to temporarily omit the subroutes or setting clearTarget to false? Can you post your routing.config?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The SplitContainer only contains a SplitContainer control ( :) ). This isn't loaded into the DOM if I'm using real routing (via the click on a menu item). However, if I go to the URL directly (or reload the page of course), the SplitContainer view is loaded fine. 
I'm got to test your suggestions and post the results. 
I've never heard of routing.config? Do you mean the MyRouter.js?

Comment: Okay falsing the cleartarget and clearing the subroutes results in a page which just looks like the start page (with the menu stuff). However, if I reload the page, I'm getting the SplitContainer view >>without<< the menu stuff. O.o So, I'm getting the same page as if I would reload the page with the initial configuration.

Comment: take out the `bReplace`

Comment: @NareshKumarDevalapally I've tested this these days and didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

you set the

```
clearTarget: true,
```

that removes the menu page from the apps pages aggregation.
If you are using navContainer and splitcontainer you should set clearTarget to false since they are building up an navigation stack and need pages to be constantly in their aggregations.

BR,
Tobias